# How to write a simple email listener in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, smtp, imap

I'm completely new to Python (v2.7) and I need to write a simple program that runs continuously, listens to a gmail account and calls a function when said account receives an email. So far it seems like using either Python's built-in IMAP or SMTP libraries seems like the best option but I'm not very familiar with them, let alone Python itself.

What I've come up with so far is able to connect to the email and find the most recent email via IMAP4 but it's lacking a way to continuously check whether a new email has been received:

([Source](https://yuji.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/python-imaplib-imap-example-with-gmail/))

```
import imaplib
import email

#logs in to the desired account and navigates to the inbox
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('email@gmail.com','password')
mail.list()
mail.select('inbox')

result, data = mail.search(None,'ALL')

#retrieves the latest (newest) email by sequential ID
ids = data[0]
id_list = ids.split()
latest_email_id = id_list[-1]
```

Any help on how I can adjust this to continuously run and check for new incoming messages would be great. Thanks!

Comment: You can use a timing thread, something like the `sched` module or any of the other various ways to create a recurring task to do this.

Comment: I think you might need to use pop3. Do look it up, I think it's email eventing, you are notified when an email comes in. But you still need to run this in the background

Comment: You can search specifically for 'NEW' if you wanted.

Comment: Please do not learn 2.7, learn Python 3, it's the future of Python, people who learn 2.7 hold the language back

Comment: imaplib, itself, does not include any eventing features, it is a very low level library.  You could poll for new mail in a loop, or you can try finding a higher level library that actually has this sort of thing built in.

Comment: @Will I'll be sure to look into Python 3. My group agreed on using 2.7 and that's the only reason I'm using it. I'll make a point to work in 3 the next time I get the chance

Comment: If you wanna read from Gmail, checkout push notifications https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push

Answer (score 1):

Use the threading module and subclass threading.Thread. Documentation can be found here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html

```
import threading
import time

class MailThread(threading.Thread):
```

then your code goes into `run()` where you have to add some delay. Let's say 1000 seconds.

```
def run():
    #your code here
    time.sleep(1000)
```

The last section of your script looks like this

```
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    mail_thread = MailThread()
    mail_thread.start()
    # do other stuff
```

OR

Just use a `while(True)` loop with `time.sleep()` and a `break` once you got mail.